# Posible traducción en español para SNAFU

Tags: traducción, modismos, solicitud-de-modismo

[SNAFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snafu) es una expresión idiomática de origen militar que significa "Situation Normal, All Fucked Up". El término tiene su origen durante la Segunda Guerra Mundial y sirve para expresar el caos y la confusión reinante desde la perspectiva de un soldado cualquiera.

La expresión se usa para describir cualquier situación ridículamente caótica en cualquier otro ámbito.

Una posible traducción al español sería "Lo normal, todo jodido" o "lo normal, todo patas arriba" o "lo normal, todo manga por hombro". ¿Hay algún modismo en español que tenga el mismo significado pero que ya incluya de por sí el "lo normal" para expresar "la situación normal en que reina el caos"?

Comment: ¿Está todo patas para arriba, como siempre?

Comment: "Posible traducción" me parece irregular

Comment: @WGroleau A menos que haya un equivalente directo para el término, que sería también una respuesta válida a la pregunta, es posible que haya varias maneras de transmitir la misma información. Distintos usuarios lo harán a su propia manera. El formato de Q&A de los stacks permite (y amina a) tener múltiples respuestas por pregunta y que la comunidad las valide mediante votos.

Comment: Lapsing into English, what I meant was the phrase "posible traducción" sounds not-quite-right.

Comment: @WGroleau **Interesting...** May I suggest [**asking a brief new question**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about it? You could expand your thoughts  and worst that can happend is that we learn something new... After all, we are here to learn. Probably someone will explain the grammar behind it and/or suggest other ways of conveying the same (probably in a more correct way) which will be really helpful for all of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Ante todo: gracias por descubrirnos este término, no lo conocía y los enlaces me hicieron llegar a otros ([*List of military slang terms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_slang_terms)) de similar hilaridad :)</sub>

*SNAFU* quiere decir *situación normal, todo jodido*, donde [*fucked-up*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=fucked-up) puede traducirse también como *hecho mierda*, *hecho polvo*, *pa la cagá*... según el país en el que se diga.

Por lo que comentas, la expresión saltó del contexto de la guerra y pasó a ser utilizada de forma habitual. Entiendo pues que uno puede llegar a casa, encontrarse a los niños corriendo en pelotas por la casa, el perro ladrando, la abuela protestando y la lavadora por tender...  y decir *estamos SNAFU*. Suponiendo que ese es el uso, podríamos utilizar algo así como ***el caos habitual***, denotando la normalidad de que todo esté patas para arriba, donde [*caos*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7HD3hMJ) es *Confusión, desorden*.

Comment: ¡Qué buenas las de _FUBAR (fucked up beyond all reason)_ y _TARFU (totally and royally fucked up)_!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¡ya te digo! Parecen sacados de [_M.A.S.H._](https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film126099.html).

Answer (score 5):

No sé si esto cuenta como respuesta exactamente, ya que se trata de una expresión elíptica con un uso retórico restringido, pero bien: en Argentina es habitual encontrar en las redes sociales la frase *"Total normalidad"* adjunta a una noticia o imagen que refiere a una situación insólita, indignante o de manifiesta inversión de las normas civilizadas. (Véase por ejemplo [este tuit](https://twitter.com/agosto/status/874235706780123136), relativo al transporte público en la ciudad de Córdoba; la custodia se hizo necesaria debido a amenazas del sindicato de chóferes.) *Total normalidad* es, por tanto, una etiqueta irónica que se adhiere a algo más y expresa más o menos lo que *FUBAR*, en el sentido de que la multiplicación de sucesos como éste nos muestran que vivimos en una "normalidad" de excepción. Es un poco difícil emplearla fuera del ámbito de las redes sociales, sin embargo.

El origen de la frase es bastante desagradable en sí mismo: se trata del [titular de tapa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_normalidad) del diario porteño *Clarín* del día 25 de marzo de 1976, inmediatamente posterior al último golpe militar.

Comment: ¿Entiendo que _tapa_ es portada?

Comment: @fedorqui Así es.

Comment: Interesante, nunca lo había oído. ¿Es común en Argentina? No lo encuentro ni [en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z6OAAxV|Z6OF72b) ni [en el DAMER](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=bly4uBRnUx0AXMs3NRx).

Comment: @fedorqui Es raro, porque no es neologismo ni nada. Formalmente sí se dice *portada* pero *tapa* es el único término usado con naturalidad.

Answer (score 2):

Por dar una alternativa, y sin extenderme más allá de lo ya comentado por ti y [por fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21216/12637): ***el típico descontrol***.

En todo caso, por buscar frases en los corpus de referencia, tenemos (negritas mías):

> *El yogui verifica con minuciosidad sus propios estados mentales, mecanismos y hábitos, experimentando interiormente y combatiendo el **descontrol habitual** de la mente, siempre vapuleada por los pares de opuestos, cambiante y sometida al conflicto, al temor y al deseo de todo tipo.*
>
> Ramiro A. Calle Capilla, "Yoga, una medicina natural", 1990 (España).

---

> *Hoy, como "novedad" no habrá transporte escolar, lo que aumentará el **habitual caos** de tráfico que padece la ciudad en las horas punta.*
>
> El Mundo, 09/01/1995 (España).

No he podido encontrar una variante de la expresión en una única palabra.

Answer (score 1):

Por si alguien viene a parar aquí yo dejo la traducción más aproximada que se me ocurrió cuando vi esta expresión en un videojuego que estaba traduciendo.
"Jodido pero contento".

Comment: "Jodido pero contento" es una traducción muy libre de "Situation Normal, All Fucked Up". La parte de "jodido" es clara, pero "contento"? De dónde sale lo de "contento"?

Answer (score 0):

En la Argentina de los últimos 50 años,  el matiz de resiliencia estoica implícito en "snafu", se puede parangonar con expresiones locales como:  "ajo, y agua..!!", o la menos sofisticada:  "boludo alegre'".